# Eclipse - Importing j2me projects

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, eclipseme

What is the correct way of importing j2me projects in Eclipse?
Im getting: No projects are found to import.
I have Eclipse Helios and EclipseME plugin.

thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the sun java wireless toolkit [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137162.html). And integrate with eclipse. Also see [how to setup Eclipse for mobile Java development](http://www.javamidlet.com/2008/01/18/how-to-setup-eclipse-for-mobile-java-development.html).

Comment: thanx. EclipseME does the job.